# Select unique text from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, design-patterns

I am having a problem selecting the unique text from database.

This is for a movie database, Let's assume I have 2 movies in the database.

1st movie is in category: Drama, Romance, War
2nd movie is in category: Drama, Thriller

What I need, is to return an array wich will display me: Drama, Romance, War, Thriller. 
My current query to mysql is the following:

> $query = 'SELECT genres FROM imdb WHERE actors LIKE "%%'.$name.'%"';

In an while loop I use "foreach", like this:

```
foreach(explode(', ', $TMPL['genres']) as $v)
                    $TMPL['genre'] .= '<option value="'.urlencode($v).'">'.($v).'</option>';
```

This is returning me all the values, including the duplicated one, like this: Drama, Romance, WarDrama,Thriller

Any clue how to sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the array_unique function on that array of your with duplicate values!

$unique_values = array_unique($TMPL['genre']);

Comment: $query = 'SELECT genres FROM imdb WHERE actors LIKE "%%'.$name.'%" order by char_length(genres) DESC';
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($TMPL = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$TMPL['genre'] = '';
foreach(explode(', ', $TMPL['genres']) as $v)
$TMPL['genre'] .= '<option value="'.urlencode($v).'">'.($v).'</option>';
$gensearch .= $skin->make();  
} this is the full code, but I don't get it how can I use array_unique in this one, btw thanks for the suggestion, the above comments with select distinct aren't helpful, since I can't use select distinct on my issue.

Comment: first of all you are selecting genres and your array index is set to genre fix that first.

Comment: basically it seems like your doing too much there.  just generate an array with all the duplicated values, then use array unique on it, then do the for each on that array.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT genres FROM imdb WHERE actors LIKE "%%'.$name.'%"';
```

would do it

Answer (score 1):

use `DISTINCT`

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT genres FROM imdb WHERE actors LIKE "%%'.$name.'%"';
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have a column with a delimited list of genres?

Loop through every row in your query and explode the genres, add every genre to a master array and then use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

If i understand you correctly you wont be able to do it (easily) with MySQL as you haven't normalised your database properly.